# Manjaro won‘t recognise nvme ssd

Tags: ssd, grub, nvme, manjaro, dualboot

So I tried to dual boot with 2 nvme ssds however **manjaro** won’t recognise my **2nd nvme ssd**.
In fact it won’t recognise any. I tried reformating it’s file system into pretty much everything and also completely wipe it with **diskpart clear all**.

I can’t select it when trying to mount it either. I now installed manjaro on another **sata ssd** which works fine, with the exception that it **won’t** show up in **grub**. I have to manually go into the inbuilt bootloader (efi) by pressing f12.

In future I would like to move manjaro to the nvme ssd.

Any help in getting it recognised would be really appreciated. If you need any code or error messages please let me know.

I have an **acer nitro an515-55**, windows recognizes my second drive, in fact it recognizes all drives, manjaro only recognizes the sata ssd, my disk models are:

**Sata:** Kioxia-excercia sata ssd
serial number: 62MB8110K0L5
**nvme ssd 1 :**(run´s windows): Fanxiang S500PRO 1TB
**nvme ssd 2 :** WDC PC SN530 SDNPZ-512G-1114

Comment: Has any other operating system recognized the 2nd SSD on this computer? What configuration works and which not? What are your computer and disk models?

Comment: And please check your firmware (UEFI) settings before anything else. If you have somewhere a drive mode setting with anything other than **AHCI** (e.g. "RAID" or "Intel RST") you should change it to AHCI because other modes aren't (yet) supported in most Linux distros.

Comment: I have an **acer nitro an515-55**, windows recognizes my second drive, in fact it recognizes all drives, manjaro only recognizes the sata ssd, my disk models are:

**Sata:** Kioxia-excercia sata ssd 
 serial number: 62MB8110K0L5
**nvme ssd 1 (run´s windows):** Fanxiang S500PRO 1TB
**nvme ssd 2 :** WDC PC SN530 SDNPZ-512G-1114

Comment: Also I tried to change the drive mode to ahci however the option is greyed out in bios and using **regedit**  to change **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\StartOverride** zero value to zero. however i still can´t change it.

Comment: After changing it to ahci everything worked with the exception of not being able to access uefi system settings anymore but thank you for your help